# IndexError: list index out of range for nested list (matrix)

Tags: python

I have been trying to solve a problem on HackerRank, and here is my solution for it, And I am receiving this error `IndexError: list index out of range` on line 21, that is, `s_sum += arr[i][n-1]`, can someone help me figure this out?

```
def diagonalDifference(arr):
    p_sum = 0
    s_sum = 0
    for i in range(n):
        p_sum += arr[i][i]
        s_sum += arr[i][n-i]
    return abs(p_sum - s_sum)

n = int(input().strip())
arr = []
for _ in range(n):
    arr.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))
result = diagonalDifference(arr)
print(result)
```

Comment: `s_sum += arr[i][n-i]` is it `n-i` or `n-1`?

Comment: @komatiraju032 it is i. the question is to calculate the absolute difference between principal diagonal and secondary diagonal.

Comment: Which line is line 21? Please provide the entire error output.

Comment: @AMC s_sum += arr[i][n-1] is the 21st line. Thank you for your help, i got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you loop -

```
for i in range(n):
    p_sum += arr[i][i]
    s_sum += arr[i][n-i]
```

Here, i starts from 0 and you have `_sum += arr[i][n-1]` which will be `arr[0][n]` in the first iteration. This will go out of bound since your `arr` can index only upto `arr[i][n-1]`. So, This is giving you `list index out of range` error.

You should do it correctly as follows -

```
for i in range(n):
    p_sum += arr[i][i]       #primary diagonal sum
    s_sum += arr[i][(n-1)-i] #secondary diagonal sum. notice the indexing arr[i][n-1-i] 
                             #which ensures that the array doesn't access out of its bounds
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: thanks for your help. can you please suggest an alternative to it then?

Comment: I would need to know the question details before I can suggest the changes

Comment: yeah sorry it was in the comment, the function must return the absolute difference between the principal diagonal and secondary diagonal of a matrix

Comment: @shrekh Check the edit. I have included the change which would give you the required result

Answer (score 1):

When `i = 0`, i.e. in the first iteration of the `for` loop, `n-i` evaluates to `n`, but that is out of bounds, if `arr` is of size `n`.

Answer (score 1):

You get *out of range* error because you run

```
s_sum += arr[i][n-i]
```

for in the range `[0:n-1]`. So, when `i = 0` your second index becomes `n`, that is out of bounds as it tries to access `arr[0][n]`.